# Hide Content of all in sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to hide only content of all while dragging or sorting the list. please help me out with this and this is my  [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/x53a0Ln8/1/).This is my jquery code used in fiddle:

```
$( function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
} );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what u want to hide there?

Comment: try with my answer, is this is what u asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using start and stop callback handler you can do that. Everything this same as your code except the script, just take a look at script

```js
/*$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ 
         start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.find(".content").hide();
         },
         stop: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.find(".content").show();
         }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    
  } );*/ // this is to hide only dragging element content
  
 $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ 
         start: function (event, ui) {
            $(".content").hide();
         },
         stop: function (event, ui) {
         $(".content").show();
         }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    
  } ); // this is to hide all elements contents
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  h1{
    font-size:12px;
  }
  .content{
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
  <h1>
  Item 1
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
 <h1>
 Item 2
 </h1> 
  
  <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
  
<h1>
  Item 3
</h1>
    <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
<h1>
  Item 4
</h1>
    <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
<h1>
  Item 5
</h1>
    <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
<h1>
  Item 6
</h1>
    <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
<h1>
  Item 7
</h1>
    <div class="content">
  Test Content
  </div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you changed the script?

Comment: Check now the script code, i have mentioned in comments, i have added the code for both if u want hide the content of only dragging element then use code in comment, else you u want to hide all content element then use code accordingly as mentioned in script code

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the contents while dragging.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.find("div.content").hide();
  },
   stop: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.find("div.content").show();
  }
});
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


  } );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x53a0Ln8/2/